# How to run Netflix Astyanax in linux

Tags: java, linux, command-line, cassandra, astyanax

I'm a newbie in running Java code in Linux environment. I'm trying to get the Astyanax to work on the linux machine. 
I followed the instruction on https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Getting-Started
I have cloned the code from github, and ./gradlew build runs successfully.

I'm trying to run the AstClient in the astyanax-examples. I tried the following command:

java -cp "/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-examples/build/libs/*;/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-cassandra/build/libs/*;/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-core/build/libs/*;/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-thrift/build/libs/*" com.netflix.astyanax.examples.AstClient

under holder:
/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-examples/build/classes/main

but I got the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/astyanax/examples/AstClient
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.astyanax.examples.AstClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: com.netflix.astyanax.examples.AstClient.  Program will exit.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:` classpath separators on *nix platforms

```
java -cp "/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-examples/build/libs/*:/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-cassandra/build/libs/*:/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-core/build/libs/*:/home/shbash6/astyanax/astyanax-thrift/build/libs/*" com.netflix.astyanax.examples.AstClient
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But a new problem appeared: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, I checked online, and someone suggest to use maven to get all required jars.

Comment: You're missing `slf4j-api.jar` - google that error message - its well documented

Comment: It seems that I still need a lot of other jars to have Astyanax running. I checked online, and someone suggested to use maven to get all required jars. Any suggestion on this? Also, I used gradlew to build the code, which is supposed to have all the required jars, but I did not find slf4j-api.jar anywhere. Also, does gradle provide an easy way to run the code?

Comment: Actually, I forgot to include the lib folder in cassandra. Now it works. Thanks!